# understanding setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout, drupal-jcarousel

I'm trying to make jcarousel work both sides

If I use the following it returns the correct alert

```
this.timer = window.setTimeout( (a === 0.5)? alert("c.next() a = " + a): 
                                (a === 0.6)? alert("c.prev() a = " + a): 
                              function(){},500 ) ;
```

but, if I replace the alert with the actual call it doesn't scroll. just moves to the next image

```
this.timer = window.setTimeout( (a === 0.5)? c.next.bind(c):
                                (a === 0.6)? c.prev.bind(c): function(){},500 ) ;
```

without bind() it doesn't work either

```
this.timer = window.setTimeout( (a === 0.5)? c.next(): 
                                (a === 0.6)? c.prev(): function(){},500 ) ;
```

Does anyone has an idea why is this happening? if I don't use any condition inside Timeout and use one of the two calls, for example c.next() then it would scroll but only from Right to Left

Any guideline will be greatly appreciated
Sandra

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't scroll, just moves to the next image"?  Isn't that what your `c.next()` function does? Your second sample of code looks like the right one; the first one doesn't really do anything and the third one is wrong.

Comment: ok. you are right. c.next() moves to the next. But, if I use: window.setTimeout( function() {c.next()}, 500 ) it scrolls to the right until the user moves the mouse out. Based on that, I've been trying to use the same function (because I can't find another way) to scroll to the left if the user hovers over the left button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it easier for yourself and define your functions ahead of time and in a way that saves you the trouble of scope and closure

```
var next = function () {return c.next();},
    prev = function () {return c.prev();},
    noop = function () {};

this.timer = window.setTimeout(
    (a === 0.5 ? next : a === 0.6 ? prev : noop),
    500
);
```

Now

1. If you want to debug a *function*, you can debug it separately to *setTimeout*.
2. It's clear which *function* is being passed into *setTimeout*.

**Edit** Also note how I'm not invoking the functions as they're passed as the argument; when one uses *setTimeout* it is because they want something invoked later, not immediately.

Comment: This works correctly, but without scrolling. Here is where we started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139359/jcarousel-autoscroll-in-two-different-directions